# Suppose $E[g(W) ] = 2E[1_{ \{V\le cW \}} g(W) ]=0$ for all $g$ where $W=V+N$ and $N$ is Gaussian iff $V$ is Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose that $W=V+N$ where $N$ is standard normal independent of $V$.   Assume that for a given constant $c >0$, the following equality holds for all functions $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align}
E[g(W) ] = 2E[1_{ \{V\le cW \}} g(W) ]
\end{align}

**Question:** Can we show that the only random variable $V$ that satisfies the above is zero mean gaussian (where variance depends on $c$)?

I know how to prove the forward direction, but not the backward direction.

**Forward Direction**
First, note
\begin{align}
E[  1_{ \{V\le cW \}} g(W) ]&=E \left[ E \left[ 1_{ \{V\le cW \}} |W  \right]g(W) \right]\\
&=E \left[ F_{V|W}(cW|W)g(W) \right]
\end{align}
thus the equation of interest can be re-written as
\begin{align}
E[g(W) ]=2E \left[ F_{V|W}(cW|W)g(W) \right], \forall g
\end{align}
where $F_{V|W}(v|w)$ is a conditional cdf.

Now note that if $V$ is gaussian then we have that $V|W=w$ is also gaussian
\begin{align}
F_{V|W}(v|w)=\Phi \left( \frac{v-E[V|W=w]}{Var(V|W=w)} \right)=\Phi \left( \frac{v-bv}{b} \right)
\end{align}
where we have used that $E[V|W=w]=bw$ and $Var(V|W=w)=b=\frac{E[VW]}{E[W^2]}=\frac{\sigma_V^2}{1+\sigma_V^2}$.
Therefore, if we choose $c=b$, then
\begin{align}
2E \left[ F_{V|W}(cW|W)g(W) \right]=2E \left[ \Phi \left( \frac{cW-bW}{b} \right) g(W)\right]=2 E \left[ \frac{1}{2} g(W)\right].
\end{align}
This concludes the proof of the direct part.

**Some thoughts** I was trying to use the [Stein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_method) equation to prove this but never could get it quite right.